# How Do I set Up A Custom Wordpress Theme To Be Able To Update It In The Themes Admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I've been looking around for info on this and haven't been having much luck...

I've developing a custom Wordpress Theme on my local machine but now it's time to start testing on a remote WP site so the team I'm working with can see development without me having to screen share constantly.

Whenever I need to push an update to the theme to the remote site, I have to disable the theme by enabling a different theme. Then I have to delete my existing theme, upload/install the latest version's .zip package and then activate it again.

What I'm wondering is how (if?) I can set something up so that I can do a one-click update like I see on other themes. Is there a way to self-host that on my remote site somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds a bit overcomplicated for me...
First of all, I would recommend using GIT and then you have it on your local machine and on the server, you push and pull changes - these will be applied with no problems + you will have history of code's changes + your development team can use it too so everybody will be up-to-date.

If you do not want any kind of code repo, instead of removing/installing/switching etc. the theme, simply upload edited file via FTP to the theme and it will work out of the box - no need of changing themes.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13/updates-for-a-private-plugin or https://github.com/afragen/github-updater

Comment: Thanks, Grzegorz. I am using a GitHub repo but I'm the sole dev (and designer) on the project so it's mainly for my own sanity right now. My next step was to check if just FTPing the theme would work, so that definitely saves me some googling and is how I'll go with it for now (if you want to turn that comment into an answer, I'll gladly mark it as the solution for my situation.) Howard: I had looked into that GitHub updater and wasn't sure if I wanted to go that route at this stage.